# Is it possible to dynamically register bundles in Symfony2?

Tags: php, symfony

I have a loader bundle (`LoaderBundle`) that should register other bundles in the same directory.

```
/Acme/LoaderBundle/...
/Acme/ToBeLoadedBundle1/...
/Acme/ToBeLoadedBundle2/...
```

I'd like to avoid manually registering every new bundle (in `Acme` directory) in `AppKernel::registerBundles()`. Preferably I'd like something in `LoaderBundle` to run on every single request and dynamically register `ToBeLoadedBundle1` and `ToBeLoadedBundle2`. Is it possible?

Comment: Try to avoid the need to make PHP open directories and/or stat files. Even with big OS caches this is detrimental to performance. Of course it could be quite handy for development.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Untested but you could try something like

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Loader\LoaderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Finder\Finder;

class AppKernel extends Kernel
{
    public function registerBundles()
    {
        $bundles = array(
            new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
            //... default bundles
        );

        if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), array('dev', 'test'))) {
            $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle();
            // ... debug and development bundles
        }

        $searchPath = __DIR__.'/../src';
        $finder     = new Finder();
        $finder->files()
               ->in($searchPath)
               ->name('*Bundle.php');

        foreach ($finder as $file) {
            $path       = substr($file->getRealpath(), strlen($searchPath) + 1, -4);
            $parts      = explode('/', $path);
            $class      = array_pop($parts);
            $namespace  = implode('\\', $parts);
            $class      = $namespace.'\\'.$class;
            $bundles[]  = new $class();
        }

        return $bundles;
    }

    public function registerContainerConfiguration(LoaderInterface $loader)
    {
        $loader->load(__DIR__.'/config/config_'.$this->getEnvironment().'.yml');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It did lead me to correct solution. I didn't realise I can work with classes normally even if bundles aren't registered yet.

Answer (score -2):

The previous answer contained a little mistake where it would include the class with a / in front, here is the updated code

```
 foreach ($finder as $file) {
            $path       = substr($file->getRealpath(), strrpos($file->getRealpath(), "src") + 4);
            $parts      = explode('/', $path);
            $class      = array_pop($parts);
            $namespace  = implode('\\', $parts);
            $class      = $namespace.'\\'.$class;
            //remove first slash
            $class = substr($class, 1, -4);
            $bundles[]  = new $class();
        }
```