# Symfony2 dynamicaly add to AppKernel

Tags: php, symfony

I have small problem. I have created class that add bundles (saved in file) to AppKernel. I need it to instal/uninstall "modules".

Changes in appKernel.php ( only return is changed )

```
$kernelManager = new KernelManager();        
return $kernelManager->addModuleBundle($bundles);
```

Now KernelManager Class ( method addModuleBundle, $this->bundles is array of my installed bundles ):

```
    public function addModuleBundle(array $bundles)
    {
        if(count($this->bundles) > 0 )
        {
            foreach($this->bundles as $namespace){
                $bundle = $namespace.'\\'.str_replace('\\' , '', $namespace);
                $bundles[] = new $bundle;
            }   
        }

        return $bundles;
    }
```

How it work: my class is call in appKernel, and it return bundles array with installed bundles ( It is nevermind ).

After installation of a module my ModuleManager performs two operations
1. Generate new file with installed bundles
2. Generate routing.yml where i add default routing to any module.

Everything works nice but after the installation of the module I receive an error

> Twig_Error_Runtime in classes.php line 4957:
>
> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template
>   ("Bundle "BUNDLENAME" does not exist or it is not enabled. Maybe you
>   forgot to add it in the registerBundles() method of your AppKernel.php
>   file? in @BUNDLENAME/Resources/config/routing.yml (which is being
>   imported from
>   "ROOT_DIR\vendor\MYBUNDLEROOT/Resources/config/routing.yml"). Make
>   sure the "BUNDLENAME/Resources/config/routing.yml" bundle is correctly
>   registered and loaded in the application kernel class. If the bundle
>   is registered, make sure the bundle path
>   "@BUNDLENAME/Resources/config/routing.yml" is not empty.") in
>   "frontend.html.twig" at line 21.

frontend.html.twig line 21:

```
<script src="{{ path('fos_js_routing_js', {"callback": "fos.Router.setData"}) }}"></script>
```

How I install module:
1. I click button install
2. My ModuleManager change module in DB to installed
3. ModuleManager generate file with installed Modules (bundles)
4. ModuleManager generate routing.yml with installed Modules
5. A browster reload to information page about success (but now I have an error).

If I will refresh browser by press f5 key error disappear.

I think that it is a problem with a cache but I cant any method to force refresh.

EDIT --------------

I have found one more thing. After install module I tried to show files with include installed Bundles. But it show only old bundle/bundles (without new = instal it this operation). When I check this file on serwer I see changes. Maybe SF2 keep this file in session or something else?

Comment: What about adding cache:clear to your module setup process?

Comment: Can you add some code or better - add some error datails? Second - where is this foreach ? Add some context.

Comment: Hi, I have tryed clear cache by using FileSystem and then remove "kernel.cache_dir" but I have got error: cannot delete twig folder. I have added some more details about error.

Comment: This Answer will help you. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6609240/is-it-possible-to-dynamically-register-bundles-in-symfony2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6609240/is-it-possible-to-dynamically-register-bundles-in-symfony2)

Comment: Hard to say whats wrong, because after second refresh it work. Waht do you think to add command `cache:clear` or/and `cache:warmup`  http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console/introduction.html#calling-an-existing-command please read notes about command order